# I am getting following error while submiting deatiles ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name

Tags: java, oracle, servlets

### Save Method

```
public static int save(Emp2 e){
    int status=0;
    try{
        Connection con=EmpDb.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into empsoft(name,dob,bplace,age,bgroup,hw,disability,gender,email,mobile,mstatus,hobbies,nationality,religion,ug,specialization,grade,university,year,ug1,specialization1,grade1,university1,year1,ug2,specialization2,grade2,university2,year2,ug3,specialization3,grade3,university3,year3,post,dep,company,city,days,post1,dep1,company1,city1,days1,post2,dep2,company2,city2,days2,preaddress,peraddress,lno,pno) values (?,?,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1,e.getEname());
        ps.setString(2,e.getDob());
        ps.setString(3, e.getBplace());
        ps.setInt(4, e.getAge());
        ps.setString(5, e.getBgroup());
        ps.setString(6, e.getHw());
        ps.setString(7, e.getDisability());
        ps.setString(8, e.getGender());
        ps.setString(9,e.getEmail());
        ps.setString(10, e.getMobileno());
        ps.setString(11, e.getMstatus());
        ps.setString(12, e.getHobbies());
        ps.setString(13, e.getNationality());
        ps.setString(14, e.getReligion());
        ps.setString(15, e.getUg());
        ps.setString(16, e.getSpecialization());
        ps.setString(17, e.getGrade());
        ps.setString(18, e.getUniversity());
        ps.setString(19, e.getYear());
        ps.setString(20, e.getUg1());
        ps.setString(21, e.getSpecialization1());
        ps.setString(22, e.getGrade1());
        ps.setString(23, e.getUniversity1());
        ps.setString(24, e.getYear1());
        ps.setString(25, e.getUg2());
        ps.setString(26, e.getSpecialization());
        ps.setString(27, e.getGrade2());
        ps.setString(28, e.getUniversity2());
        ps.setString(29, e.getYear2());
        ps.setString(30, e.getUg3());
        ps.setString(31, e.getSpecialization3());
        ps.setString(32, e.getGrade3());
        ps.setString(33, e.getUniversity3());
        ps.setString(34, e.getYear3());
        ps.setString(35, e.getPost());
        ps.setString(36, e.getDep());
        ps.setString(37, e.getCompany());
        ps.setString(38, e.getCity());
        ps.setString(39, e.getDays());
        ps.setString(40, e.getPost1());
        ps.setString(41, e.getDep1());
        ps.setString(42, e.getCompany1());
        ps.setString(43, e.getCity1());
        ps.setString(44, e.getDays1());
        ps.setString(45, e.getPost2());
        ps.setString(46, e.getDep2());
        ps.setString(47, e.getCompany2());
        ps.setString(48, e.getCity2());
        ps.setString(49, e.getDays2());
        ps.setString(50, e.getPreaddress());
        ps.setString(51, e.getPeraddress());
        ps.setString(52, e.getLno());
        ps.setString(53, e.getPno());
        status=ps.executeUpdate();
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();   
    }

    return status;
}
```

### Save Servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
    String ename=req.getParameter("ename");
    String dob=req.getParameter("dob");
    String bplace=req.getParameter("bplace");
    String ag=req.getParameter("age");
    int age=Integer.parseInt(ag);
    String bgroup=req.getParameter("bgroup");
    String hw=req.getParameter("hw");
    String disability=req.getParameter("disability");
    String gender=req.getParameter("gender");
    String email=req.getParameter("email");
    String mobileno=req.getParameter("mobileno");
    String mstatus=req.getParameter("mstatus");
    String hobbies=req.getParameter("hobbies");
    String nationality=req.getParameter("nationality");
    String religion=req.getParameter("religion");
    String ug=req.getParameter("ug");
    String specialization=req.getParameter("specialization");
    String grade=req.getParameter("grade");
    String university=req.getParameter("university");
    String year=req.getParameter("year");
    String ug1=req.getParameter("ug1");
    String specialization1=req.getParameter("specialization1");
    String grade1=req.getParameter("grade1");
    String university1=req.getParameter("university1");
    String year1=req.getParameter("year1");
    String ug2=req.getParameter("ug2");
    String specialization2=req.getParameter("specialization2");
    String grade2=req.getParameter("grade2");
    String university2=req.getParameter("university2");
    String year2=req.getParameter("year2");
    String ug3=req.getParameter("ug3");
    String specialization3=req.getParameter("specialization3");
    String grade3=req.getParameter("grade3");
    String university3=req.getParameter("university3");
    String year3=req.getParameter("year3");
    String post=req.getParameter("post");
    String dep=req.getParameter("dep");
    String company=req.getParameter("company");
    String city=req.getParameter("city");
    String days=req.getParameter("days");
    String post1=req.getParameter("post1");
    String dep1=req.getParameter("dep1");
    String company1=req.getParameter("company1");
    String city1=req.getParameter("city1");
    String days1=req.getParameter("days1");
    String post2=req.getParameter("post2");
    String dep2=req.getParameter("dep2");
    String company2=req.getParameter("company2");
    String city2=req.getParameter("city2");
    String days2=req.getParameter("days2");
    String preaddress=req.getParameter("preaddress");
    String peraddress=req.getParameter("peraddress");
    String lno=req.getParameter("lno");
    String pno=req.getParameter("pno");

    Emp2 e=new Emp2();
    e.setEname(ename);
    e.setDob(dob);
    e.setBplace(bplace);
    e.setAge(age);
    e.setBgroup(bgroup);
    e.setHw(hw);
    e.setDisability(disability);
    e.setGender(gender);
    e.setEmail(email);
    e.setMobileno(mobileno);
    e.setMstatus(mstatus);
    e.setHobbies(hobbies);
    e.setNationality(nationality);
    e.setReligion(religion);
    e.setUg(ug);
    e.setSpecialization(specialization);
    e.setGrade(grade);
    e.setUniversity(university);
    e.setYear(year);
    e.setUg1(ug1);
    e.setSpecialization(specialization1);
    e.setGrade1(grade1);
    e.setUniversity(university1);
    e.setYear1(year1);
    e.setUg2(ug2);
    e.setSpecialization2(specialization2);
    e.setGrade2(grade2);
    e.setUniversity2(university2);
    e.setYear2(year2);
    e.setUg3(ug3);
    e.setSpecialization3(specialization3);
    e.setGrade3(grade3);
    e.setUniversity3(university3);
    e.setYear3(year3);
    e.setPost(post);
    e.setDep(dep);
    e.setCompany(company);
    e.setCity(city);
    e.setDays(days);
    e.setPost1(post1);
    e.setDep1(dep1);
    e.setCompany1(company1);
    e.setCity1(city1);
    e.setDays1(days1);
    e.setPost2(post2);
    e.setDep2(dep2);
    e.setCompany2(company2);
    e.setCity2(city2);
    e.setDays2(days2);
    e.setPreaddress(preaddress);
    e.setPeraddress(peraddress);
    e.setLno(lno);
    e.setPno(pno);
    int status=EmpDb.save(e);
    if(status>0){
        out.print("<p>Record saved successfully!</p>");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("EmpRegis.html").include(req, res);
    }else{
        out.println("Sorry! unable to save record");
    }

    out.close();
}
```

### DataBase

```
CREATE TABLE  "EMPSOFT" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "ENAME" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DOB" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "BPLACE" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "AGE" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "BGROUP" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "HW" VARCHAR2(400) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DISABILITY" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GENDER" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MOBILENO" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MSTATUS" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "HOBBIES" VARCHAR2(400) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NATIONALITY" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "RELIGION" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UG" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SPECIALIZATION" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GRADE" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UNIVERSITY" VARCHAR2(400) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "YEAR" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UG1" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SPECIALIZATION1" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GRADE1" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UNIVERSITY1" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "YEAR1" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UG2" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SPECIALIZATION2" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GRADE2" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UNIVERSITY2" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "YEAR2" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UG3" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "SPECIALIZATION3" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "GRADE3" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "UNIVERSITY3" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "YEAR3" DATE, 
    "POST" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "DEP" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "COMPANY" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "DAYS" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "POST1" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "DEP1" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "COMPANY1" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "CITY1" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "DAYS1" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "POST2" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "DEP2" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "COMPANY2" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "CITY2" VARCHAR2(400), 
    "DAYS2" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "PREADDRESS" VARCHAR2(400) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PERADDRESS" VARCHAR2(400) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LNO" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PNO" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "EMPSOFT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
   )
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a comma missing:

```
PreparedStatement ps= ... values (?,?,?,?,??,?,?,...
                                           ^
```

You should think about normalizing your datamodel. At least I can see a table person, education and address.

Comment: Thank you Thomas i got it but
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331at com.servlet.EmpDb.save(EmpDb.java:75)
 at com.servlet.SaveServlet.doPost(SaveServlet.java:130)

Comment: This might be a problem with the date columns. Does getDop() return java.sql.Date?